# Magento 2 resize category & product image

Tags: image, magento-2.1.1

I want to resize category & product images for custom widget and I prefer Magento default function so I found following code to do so but I think it's for Magento 1

```
$imageObj = new Varien_Image ( $imageUrl );
$imageObj=$imageObj->constrainOnly ( true )
->keepAspectRatio ( true )
->keepFrame ( false )
->quality ( $quality )
->resize ( $width, $height )
->save ( $imageResized );
```

So I wish to know that does Magento 2 provide any function to resize,crop,scale any images including category,product etc.??

Answer (score 14):

You can get all image related methods for category and product from helper file inside Magento_Catalog module core file,

**`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php`**

List of methods are

- resize()
- List item
- keepAspectRatio()
- setQuality()
- keepFrame()
- keepTransparency()

  **$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');**

**`<img src="<?php echo $_imagehelper->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('400', '400'); ?>" />`**

> this is to use in version 2.2. the image type was changed

**`<img src="<?php echo $_imagehelper->init($_product, 'product_base_image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('400', '400'); ?>" />`**

> For custom Image Resize section

Inside Block file,

```
protected $_filesystem ;
   protected $_imageFactory;
   public function __construct(            
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory ,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,       
        ) {         
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory; 
           $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
        }

    // pass imagename, width and height
    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;

        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;         
        //create image factory...
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
        $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
        //destination folder                
        $destination = $imageResized ;    
        //save image      
        $imageResize->save($destination);         

        $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
        return $resizedURL;
  }
```

Call inside template file `$block->resize('img.jpg',300,300);`

Comment: That is for product images only I guess, I also want to resize custom images and category images as well so any idea regarding that??

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: Well nice work around, But I simply want to pass the image url in function, I tried with above code but didn't worked for me can you help please??

Comment: you have to modify content under $absolutePath in resize block and check it, currently we have display image saved location from folder, you have to change here.  OR just set image url for $absolutePath and check

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: @KaushalSuthar i fixed the answere for Magento 2.2

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya code works very well for resizing the category images with block file. But can we resize the image by height and not by width?