# product image resize in product page

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me to resize the product page product image in magento2

please find the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137766/magento-2-resize-category-product-image

Comment: Can you please help me where to edit the file location in magento2 for product page

Comment: Open template path hints from admin panel. You will see which page is showing up.

Comment: its showing product for gallary.phtml file its correct file to edit product page

Comment: gallery.phtml should be a file for thumbnail images..not for the main image. But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$productImage = $_imageHelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a theme: Copy the file [vendor]/[theme]/etc/view.xml from your base theme into your own theme, and edit the relevant image size values. I think it might be `product_page_image_medium`.

Make sure you copy the **whole** file, not just the image setting, or it will break other things. There is no inheritance mechanism for this file.