# CollectionFactory get image, thumbnail, small_image are the same

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-collection

In my custom block, I get Product Collection use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`, when I output one product in it, the image, thumbnail, small_image are the same url like below, a large image(1380px x 1340px) url：

```
[image] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
[small_image] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
[thumbnail] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
```

Did I do something wrong? How do I get the real small_image or thumbnail URL from product collection?

### More question description

For example, in the default luma theme category, product list always get the image like below:

```
<img class="product-image-photo" src="http://local.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/w/t/wt09-white_main.jpg" width="240" height="300" alt="Breathe-Easy Tank">
```

How can I get that?

### My code example

Below is my code, I remove some function for simplicity.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Template\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Product extends Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $skus = $this->getData('products_count');
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'sku', array('in' => $skus)
            );
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your code that you have used.

Comment: @Suman-PHP4U Hi, add the code now.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should  use `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image ' resize the product image

```
$resizedImage = $this->_productImageHelper->init($product, 'product_small_image')
                                           ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                           ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                           ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                                           ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                           ->resize(200, 300);
```

[Magento 2 resize category & product image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137766/magento-2-resize-category-product-image)

https://www.mageplaza.com/how-change-product-image-size-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks first, you maybe mistake my question, I can show the image,  but my problem is when get image, thumbnail, small_image, they are all the same, I always get a big image, so my question is how can I get the small image? The real small_image or thumbnail URL

Comment: Mean you want resize image

Comment: For example, in the default luma theme category, product list always get the image like `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/w/t/wt09-white_main.jpg`, how can i get that?

Comment: Please check update answer

Comment: Up vote, the resize is a solution, but can we directly get the small image that category page generated? Instead of generating some new size version images.

Comment: By the way, what is the meaning of `constrainOnly` in _productImageHelper?

Comment: Thanks anyway. Raise a new question about that [The meaning of “constrainOnly” in \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137766/magento-2-resize-category-product-image)

Answer (score 0):

Get product image from Product in PHTML file for Magento 2

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

<?php $thumbnail_image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>

<?php $small_image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_small_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>

<?php $base_image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>
```