# Magento2 : How to apply different image size in multiple categories?

Tags: magento2, category, product-images, category-products

I want to show different size images on multiple categories.

let suppose I have 3 categories : 
**- `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`**

I want to show images as below:

> => **cat1 want to show 240 x 240 images**
>
> => **cat2 350 x 350**
>
> => **cat3 500 x 500**

How can I achieve this functionality?

Can I use different size images for multiple categories?

Any help? Thank in advance.

**I also tried with a showing list view on one category and grid view for the second category.
also, change the product image size in theme view.xml but not working.**

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
    <width>500</width>
    <height>500</height>
</image>
```

But still, images size is showing 240 * 300 in the list view. Don't know why it is not resized?

Comment: You need create a resize module to show different  images size according to the category..

Comment: You can check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137766/magento-2-resize-category-product-image/#137780

Comment: which file do I need to override for develop module?

Comment: Also you can check this github module https://github.com/staempfli/magento2-module-image-resizer